# Beginner C++ Using accessors / getters to pull data from a private member variable (2D array)

Tags: c++, getter, multidimensional-array, accessor, private-members

total noob here with about 2 months of C++ experience (no other background) so go easy on me.

I am writing a battleship game for a programming assignment. The game grid is 15X20 and I am trying to have the grid as a private member variable of the class `player`.

My question is:

If the class `player` has a private member variable:

```
char playgrid[15][20];
```

Is there any reason why an accessor function, defined as:

```
char getgrid(int index1, int index2)
{
    return playgrid[index1][index2];
}
```

wouldn't work?

It's doing my head in. The error I am getting is:

> c2065: 'playgrid' undeclared identifier

which points to the line `return playgrid[val1][val2]` within the accessor definition.

While trying to figure this out, I've successfully used my getters to pull values from other private member variables, so everything else is working properly within the object after it is created. I'm definitely not misspelling anything or misusing capitalization. In my constructor, playgrid is initialized as follows:

```
int i, j;

for (i=0; i<15; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<20; j++)
    {
        playgrid[i][j]='o';
    }
}
```

What gives?

Comment: Show us the whole class.

Comment: please format your code so it's not a pain to read it. Since you are new to this, I've done it for you.

Comment: I think we need the full definition of your class and information where is your getter defined.

Comment: @Johannes - Thanks!!
@ Alexander and Maciej - Jim has sorted it for me. Scope issue! Dumb mistake on my part. Thanks for the help all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any reason why an accessor
>   function, defined as:
>
> ```
> char getgrid(int index1, int index2)
> {
> return playgrid[index1][index2];
> }
> ```
>
> wouldn't work?

Yes. A function declared like this would not be a member function of a class. You probably meant

```
char player::getgrid(int index1, int index2)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: hahaha wow... ::bangs head on desk:: 

I mean really? Can't believe i missed that. Thank you!

Comment: An accessor should be _const_ qualified, `char player::getgrid(int index1, int index2) const { .. }`.